# How to give default shape and color in tibco spotfire scatter plot, if there is no row for a set a x and y axis values

Tags: tibco, spotfire

Hi can some one please help me to solve this issue.
I'm using a scatter plot similar to the image shown below[image]

here there are blank spaces where there are no rows in the table, like in B1 and C3.

I want to replace these blank spaces with default shape and color. can some one please suggest me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to represent data points that aren't in the underlying data table. A workaround would be simply adding those rows to the table (B1-NA,C3-NA etc).

Comment: Yes that would be a simple solution, but the problem is, am getting the table through a query, so i don't get to alter the table before bringing it into  spot fire

Comment: Right now am using a R script to create a new table with those rows inserted, I wanna know is there any straight forward method to implement it.

Comment: Try exploring Insert > Rows. There's different methods there. Sorry that's all I can help with.